# How to create archive page for taxonomy terms within custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I am needing to create an archive page custom taxonomy terms that are within a custom post type.  It's set up as CPT > Custom Taxonomy > Taxonomy Terms.

I have a custom post type called "Projects," and when creating the post, the user is to select a type of project for the listing (i.e. Construction, Maintenance, etc.).  But, I need to create archive pages for the individual terms.  I've been searching and working at it via trial-and-error for hours and just keep banging my head into the wall.

Comment: The problem with that is it brings up an archive for ALL the taxonomy terms...I need three separate archives for three separate taxonomy terms.

Comment: Not sure what kind of voodoo that was, but it works...and automatically rewrote the url according to my permalink structure.  So, idk if I've been missing something or if it was a combination of several things, but I'm not where I wanted to be.  You are a saint...and I feel like an idiot  :-)

Comment: I elaborated a little on that and added this as a separate answer to your question.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer to give this question some peace? You stated that it provides what you asked for in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [example in the WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) which should work for you:

Try the following naming convention for your taxonomy term archive template:

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
```

So, let's say you have a CPT named "Projects," a taxonomy named "Maintenance," and a term within the taxonomy named "Professional." Then your naming convention would be:

```
taxonomy-maintenance-professional.php
```

Comment: This template is useful if you want a specific term to be displayed different from other terms of the same taxonomy. But maybe I got the question wrong.

Comment: I've tried that in a million different ways, and I still get nothing except a 404.  I've refreshed my permalinks, but still nothing.  I assume accessing the archive would be done by going to http://example.com/project/project-type/construction, right?

Comment: And, the taxonomy template simply goes into the theme directory with all my other templates, correct?  (Sounds stupid to ask, but just trying to rule anything out.)

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: It depends on how you've configured the slug. Try opening the term list in the admin panel and clicking "view" to make sure you're on the right URL.

Answer (score 1):

First, WordPress does not offer any built-in solution to *displaying posts of a specific post type and a specific taxonomy term*. I'm talking about something like `get_term_archive_link_for_post_type( $term, $post_type )` or so.

So you have to do this yourself.

Of course, you could create a page, name it *Construction Projects*, give it a new page template, in which you set up a custom query and display exactly what you want to. But that's not even necessary.

---

WordPress can handle several query vars—one of these is the one your taxonomy *creates*.

Suppose you have a Custom Post Type with the slug `projects`.
Then you have a Custom Taxonomy having the slug `project_type`.
And you have a term with the slug `construction` in this very taxonomy.

Then visiting `?post_type=projects&project_type=construction` will display an archive of all *Projects* having (at least) *Construction* set as *Project type*.

WordPress will interprete this query as a *Term archive* and hence rewrite the URL according to your permalink settings, and attach the post type as query var to the URL. In the *usual* case, this would lead to `/project_type/construction?post_type=projects`.

<sub>Note: You can explicitly alter the query var for a custom taxonomy. In that case, using the taxonmy slug as query var (e.g., `project_type=construction`) won't work any longer. You have to use the query var that you explicitly defined using `register_taxonomy` then.</sub>

---

And here is some example of setting up a link list for all terms of a specific taxonomy:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'    => 'name', 
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => TRUE, 
    'fields'     => 'all', 
); 
$terms = get_terms( 'project_type', $args);

if (
    ! is_wp_error( $terms )
    && ! empty( $terms )
) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $url = get_term_link( $term );
        if ( is_wp_error( $url ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $url = add_query_arg( 'post_type', 'projects', $url );
        printf(
            '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',
            $url,
            $term->name
        );
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Which template type would this use? `archive-custom_post_type.php` or a taxonomy one?

Answer (score 1):

I like to make a different Example for tfrommen's (correct) answer, because there is not a lot to find about this topic on the web.

```
  $post_type = get_post_type();

  if ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
    $related_terms = get_terms(array(
      'taxonomy' => $taxonomies
    ));
  }
```

...

```
  if ( !empty($related_terms) && !is_wp_error($related_terms) ) {
    foreach ( $related_terms as $related_term ) {
      $term_url = get_term_link($related_term);

      if ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
        $term_url = add_query_arg( 'post_type', $post_type, $term_url );
      }
?>
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url($term_url); ?>"><?php echo $related_term->name; ?></a>
<?php    }
  }
```